# Correct SQL Query - Updating records where title matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table called `winenames` with the columns `ID` and 'WineName'.

I have another table called `wineinfo` with the columns `name_id` and `WineName` and `year`

in the wineinfo table, the name_id is empty, but has around 3000 records with data in WineName column.

I am wondering if there is a SQL Query that

1. will check the table `wineinfo` and if the row 'WineName' matches any in the table `winenames` it grabs the ID and puts that ID into name_id.

Example : My wine names looks like this

```
WineName     ID

Wine1        1
Wine2        2
Wine3        3
Wine4        4
```

My wineinfo looks like this

```
WineName    name_id     year 
Wine1                   2018
Wine1                   2017
Wine1                   2013
Wine1                   2012
Wine2                   2018
Wine2                   2011
Wine2                   2019
```

My plan is to remove the winename column from the above table and just have the corrosponding ID in the name_id column.

Comment: so the column WineName in both `winenames` and `wineinfo` has different data?

Comment: @venky__ I have updated the original question - hope it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `update`:

```
update wineinfo wi join
       winenames wn
       on wi.winename = wn.winename 
    set wi.name_id = wn.id;
```

After doing this, you should probably remove the `winename` column from `wineinfo`.  It is better to keep this information in one place.  You will then need to fix the data ingestion process so it always assigns the correct id.